# AngularJS passing scope variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have javascript code in a page inside my AngularJS app which I need to send a scope variable to it, so I was wondering if that is possible in AngularJS and if yes, how? Thanks

index.html:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
        var options = { 
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                 xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', ###Need to pass scope var here### );
            }
        }; 
      ....
      ....
    }); 
</script>

    <div>
      <p>
          {{pageDescription}}
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have this outside Angular? Either way, you can do `angular.element(elemWithinScope).scope().variableNameHere;`

Comment: @tymeJV Because I failed to find an appropriate way to post files in AngularJS as form data, made a lot of research, asked here before, tried many AngularJS modules but none worked, the only thing that worked smoothly without complications was JQuery :)

Comment: @tymeJV just tried angular.element('[ng-controller=clientController]').scope(). pageDescription; but it didn't work as I got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageDescription' of undefined, taken in consideration that pageDescription is defined in the controller as a variable